# Opening the application from the results google.com, always directs to the home page of WebView Android

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

I apologize for my English.

I have a problem with redirecting to a subpage of Google results, SMS to WebView Android applications.

**Example**: The page with the address https://siteadress.pl/category in the Google results opens the WebView application and shows the homepage (https://siteadress.pl/) 
[**LOOK PICTURE**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1a2J.jpg)

**Example**: A page with the exact product https://siteadress.pl/shop/productxyz in Google results also opens the WebView application and shows the homepage. Why?

The link (https://siteadress.pl/shop/productxyz) from the sms message also opens the WebView application and shows the main page.

I want to point to the exact page of the application in WebView, not the homepage. :(

My **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="pl.APP">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="APP"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data
                android:name="asset_statements"
                android:resource="@string/asset_statements" />

        <activity
                android:name=".SplashScreen"
                android:launchMode="singleTop"
                android:noHistory="true"
                android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>


            <meta-data
                    android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
                    android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />
        </activity>


        <activity android:name=".ContactActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".CategoryActivity" />



        <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:launchMode="singleTop"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                        android:scheme="https"
                        android:host="siteadress.pl" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

My **MainActivity.xml**

```
package pl.APP

import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.util.Log
import android.webkit.URLUtil
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import android.widget.Toast
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*



class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        webView.webViewClient = MyWebViewClient()
        webView.loadUrl("https://siteadress.pl/")
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack()
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }

    inner class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient()
    {
        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean
        {
            if(URLUtil.isNetworkUrl(url))
            {
                return false
            }
            try
            {
                val shareIntent= Intent()
                shareIntent.action=Intent.ACTION_VIEW
                shareIntent.data= Uri.parse(url)
                startActivity(shareIntent)
            }
            catch(e: ActivityNotFoundException)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Appropriate app not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                Log.e("AndroidRide",e.toString())
            }
            return true
        }
        @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?): Boolean
        {
            val url=request?.url.toString()
            if(URLUtil.isNetworkUrl(url))
            {
                return false
            }
            try
            {
                val shareIntent= Intent()
                shareIntent.action=Intent.ACTION_VIEW
                shareIntent.data= Uri.parse(url)
                startActivity(shareIntent)
            }
            catch(e: ActivityNotFoundException)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Appropriate app not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                Log.e("AndroidRide",e.toString())
            }
            return true

        }

    }


}
```

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Perhaps the title of your question should be in the form of a question and without "KOTLIN" in it. If you prefer answers with example code in Kotlin, you should ask that in the body of your question post instead of the title. If your question is "why does my webview only open `https:/siteadress.pl/`" then it's because of this line `webView.loadUrl("https:/siteadress.pl/")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is you need to handle app link first, get the correct link and then load that link into your WeView:

```
Uri data = getIntent().getData();

if (data != null) {
    String url = data.toString();
    webView.loadUrl(url);
} else {
    webView.loadUrl("https://siteadress.pl/");
}
```

Comment: I'm trying. Link redirection now works. Turning on the application does not work now. I am a poor programmer. Will you help

Comment: @sadam1989 I updated the answer. It should work now.

Comment: receives information: Condition 'url != null' is always 'true'

Comment: I have corrected your code. Make Project ok. Redirection works. I turn on the simulator, application (white page). I give up...

Comment: @sadam1989 I'm sorry I keep getting it wrong. I have updated my code. I am now 100% sure this works.

Answer (score 0):

Done! This version in "Kotlin" work:

```
val url = intent.data.toString()

if (URLUtil.isValidUrl(url)) {
    webView.loadUrl(url)
} else {
    webView.loadUrl("https://siteadress.pl/")
}
```

Thanks for help :) ufff